# EF Core 3.1 - DB First and Inheritance

Tags: sql, database, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

I've created in my database 3 tables, each one with a primary key.

```
Person, Man, Woman
```

The idea is that Man and Woman inherit from Person, so their primary keys are also a FK to the Person PK.

I generate the model with the Scaffold-DbContext command and obviously I don't get any inheritance in my models, hence I explicitly do it...:

```
Man : Person {...}
Woman : Person {...}
```

However there is still something missing, since I get a runtime error:
    "A key cannot be configured on 'Man' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'Person'."

If I do it, then I get an error the other way around saying that I should set the Key not in the base class but in the derived class.

Is there any solution for that using the DB First approach?

I don't mind how internally the DB looks like (1 table is also fine with a discriminator), I just want inheritance in my model.

Thank you

Comment: Create a code first model to see the pattern, and you will see what the tables need to look like.

Comment: [This guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) about inheritance in EF Core shows only the parent class has the key column. There is a single database table that uses a discriminator in the example.

Comment: You mean that If I define the DB properly (1 Table using a Discriminator field), then when I run the command Scaffold-DbContext, I will get the model with inheritance and also the DBContext properly set?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is the TPT or table per type relational inheritance pattern. EF Core only supports TPH, or table per hierarchy. In TPH, all the properties for all subtypes go into the one table for the base type and a discriminator column is added to indicate the actual type. There is a *long* standing [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/2266) regarding this, which *finally* is starting to get some traction after 6 years. It's targeted for EF Core 5.0, though, so we're still a year out at least, unless it slips further.

Comment: TPH would work for me as well. However, i found out that with Code first is quite easy to implement it, but with DB first I am not really sure.
Would it just be a matter of defining in the DB a Discriminator column and then run the scaffold command? Or would I still need to do something else?
Thanks